# RoutePrefix() and Route Error:404 in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a navigation page(angularJS controller) from which it goes to a specific MVC controller:

```
$scope.Department = function () {
    window.location.href = appSetting.publish + "/Settings/Departments";
}
```

There is a `SettingsController` which is:

```
public class SettingsController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult Departments()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly until I tried using this:

```
$scope.Department = function () {
    window.location.href = appSetting.publish + "/appsettings/Departments";
}
```

and the controller to this:

```
[RoutePrefix("appsettings")]
public class SettingsController : Controller
{           
    [Route("Departments")]
    public ActionResult Departments()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It goes to Http error 404 not found page.
I have referred [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/web-api-route-and-route-prefix-part-2/).

There were other posts as well where it was mentioned to go to global.asax class and add the following line of code:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

And in `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And in `RouteConfig`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    }
}
```

I have all these. I checked if I have AttributeRouting (ASP.NET MVC) alongside AttributeRouting (ASP.NET Web API) in NuGet package and both were not installed so I just tried with AttributeRouting (ASP.NET MVC) but it got me the same error.

Comment: Can you confirm that attribute routing is enabled?

Comment: sorry that post dint tell anything as such. could you please elaborate a bit ? thanks

Comment: Ok that post refers to web api, but you are using plain mvc. confirm what version of asp.net that you are using, is it plain asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api or asp.net-core?

Comment: asp.net-web-api

Comment: This contradicts what you said was working. web api has no views and their controllers inherit from `ApiController` unless in asp.net-core. Oce you can clarify exactly what version you are using the correct infotmatino can be provided to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought u asked for my solution build base. this is new for me so it replied as such.

Comment: Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Yes I did refer this article as well but in vain

Comment: any help guys ? anyone ? I'm not able to figure out where it is going wrong